# Interpretation of the SQL operator EXISTS in subquery?

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I'm taking an online course about database.
Now I understand the following query

```
SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2);
```

which is something like

`SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE TRUE;`

but coming to the subquery with EXISTS,I am falling into confusion.

(College has (name, state) as its key.)
the following query seeks the name of colleges that has other colleges in the same state.

```
SELECT name,state 
FROM College C1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM College C2 
              WHERE C1.state = C2.state and C1.name != C2.name);
```

The subquery will return a relation, right? since it inside a parenthesis, it is computed first.

And the returned relation actually exists due to my artifact-designed table.
 So the EXISTS operator is always return TRUE, the result is a full table with selected columns.

Edits:
sorry for not good demostration. here is my relation

```
Standford CA
Berkley CA
MIT MA
```

the true result is

```
Standford CA
Berkley CA
```

but I think it should be

```
Standford CA
Berkley CA
MIT MA
```

Apparently there's bug in my line of reasoning.
Could you tell me where it is and what need to be corrected.

Comment: It looks fine to me. I assume you have verified that there are colleges with no other colleges in the same state?

Comment: You are performing a correlated sub-query by joining C1 & C2 which means the exists query is executed once per row of C1

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/385119/1 proves that this should work as is

Comment: edited for adding demo relation and result,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a correlated subquery or anything like that in this case, I don't think.  You can just join college to college where the states are the same and the colleges are not:

```
SELECT c1.name,c1.state 
FROM College C1,
College C2 
WHERE C1.state = C2.state and C1.name != C2.name
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb4b67/1)

If you want to do some reading on correlated sub-queries, here's a good resource:

[Clicky!](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you think that you should get all of the rows, but I will try to explain the `EXISTS` a little better since you seem to think that all it does is return true?

`EXISTS` runs its query and returns true if ANY rows are returned and false if 0 rows are returned*. In your case, your query is asking for all colleges that have more than one school in the state. So, that is why it is excluding MIT (it only has 1 school). The reason I summarize your query to mean the above is because you are taking each row and cross-referencing against the same table, except this time including schools with the same state and then excluding the current school being checked.

*In fact, the select statement is an artifact of SQL and is not even executed. Often you will see people do `SELECT 1`.

Comment: thanks,I probably found the solution to my question in the link Andrew provided so I attributed the answer to him. At first I did think the subquery as a independent and one-off query (just like IN operator receive a relation from one-off independent query). But by the resources of link, virtually the correlated subquery is not like a one-off query, it more like check if the condition exist row by row.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name,state 
FROM College C1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM College C2 
              WHERE C1.state = C2.state and C1.name != C2.name);
```

In English is roughly

> > Select the columns name and state from the college table where there is a college that is in the same state and has a different name.

So the result make perfect sense.

Answer (score -1):

To get the names of colleges where the state has more than one, I would do this.

```
select name, state, records -1 others
from college c1
join (select state st, count(*) records
from college
group by state
having count(*) > 1) temp on state = st
```